# `string index out of range 0` how to resolve it?

Tags: kotlin

The `toCamelCase` function takes in any kind of string and converts it into camelCase or Pascal case;

```
fun toCamelCase(str:String): String {
     var ans: String = str[0].toString()
    for(i in 1..str.length - 1) {
        if(str[i] != '-' && str[i] != '_' ) {
            ans += str[i]
        }
    }
    return ans
}
```

But the code above produces the following error

```
String index out of range: 0
```

I am a novice so please help me understand.

Edit: This piece of code worked out without any error in Kotlin playground( online kotlin editor)
but is not working in codewars website

Comment: For character manipulation, I'll recommend to use the StringBuilder, StringBuilder.append(), and StringBuilder.toString() at the end. Instead of concatenating the string again and again which creates hundred of String instances when hundred character string is passed into the function.

Answer (score 3):

I think your code may provide that kind of error if you call your function with an empty string: e.g. `toCamelCase("")`. This is because you try to access index 0 regardless of the input string (in `str[0].toString()`).

To avoid that, you should build your `ans` from an empty string and append characters starting from index 0, for example changing your `for(i in 1..str.length - 1)` to `for(i in 0..str.length - 1)`.

An example fix can be as follows:

```
fun toCamelCase(str:String): String {
    var ans: String = ""
    for(i in 0..str.length - 1) {
        if(str[i] != '-' && str[i] != '_' ) {
            ans += str[i]
        }
    }
    return ans
}
```